# Yii : Products with MANY_MANY categories and categories may or not has parent. Get all products

Tags: php, mysql, product, yii

I Have the following SQL schema:

**tbl_products**:
 - id 
 - id_category

**tbl_categories**:
 - id
 - id_parent

**tbl_products_categories**: - id_product - id_category

My question is: In my categories model, what kind of relation I have to declare to get all products from this category and from it's childs ? Can I get all products from a relation or will I have to make a method to loop for each child-category and later merge all products and return it?

Anyone have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Nested relationships, such as among categories or menu items, are notoriously tricky.  The case is a bit simpler when you have constraints, such as a maximum number of children. In that case, your Product's criteria would contain as many joins as you have possible relationships (I wouldn't use Yii's relational active record in this case; would it make it too complicated in my opinion).

Otherwise, yes, your best bet is to loop recursively through each relationship and return a merged array.  NOTE: this can be incredibly performance intensive, so you'll probably want to do some sort of caching on pages where this action is performed.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is many to many, each product can be associated with the current desired children and all its parents, so when you query a parent, all children products will also be parent products.